# Visual Studio 2015 (and 2013) Build and Clean Fails with no errors but MSBuild (v14) succeeds

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

My ASP.net Web Application solution will not build nor clean in Visual Studio 2015 and VS2013.
It was originally written in VS 2010.  The same sln (consisting of 3 projects) builds just fine in VS 2010 and VS 2012 but I get build failure on all 3 when building the solution or the individual projects as well as cleaning them.
There are NO errors and nothing is shown in the output window even with verbosity set to diagnostic.
There have on occasion been some warnings with regard to files not up-to-date but those are shortlived and not completely reproducible.

I'm able to successfully build via msbuild in the VS14 command line so this has got to be something IDE related.

Any suggestions out there?

I've seen numerous posts on this type of problem and none of the suggested workarounds/fixes work for my problem.
Also, what I'm experiencing is not exactly the same as I've seen posted.
I've just upgraded to the latest "update 1" available from MSDN and that didn't help.

tia
ryan

Comment: checked the framework version ?

Comment: Yes.  I've gone through the commonly reported issues like version mismatches in projects.
If this were the case, wouldn't it also fail in VS2010 and VS2012?  Not to mention the build it succeeds when I use command line msbuild with the VS2015 version.